# How to formulate a formula using logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

So I used SPSS for the possible RGB of fire and I got this as a result.
How do I make a formula to predict the possibility of fire using another set of data (RGB)

I tried using the formula P = -14.039 + (0.101*red) + (0.034*green) + (-0.119*blue)  but I keep getting answer above 1 or below 0. I thought the answer should be in between 0 and 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), or a statistics textbook. The equation obtained in logistic regression is for a *function* of the probability, the log-odds (logit), not the probability itself. Other so-called "link" functions are possible in related generalized linear models, however, so check the manual for your statistics program to be sure you are doing standard logistic regression based on the logit.